# Is this approach to server based data storage on the right track?

Tags: php, mysql, rest, security, database-design

I've written an Android game and need to store the game state on my game server. I am pretty much a novice at  is right for the above mentioned application. My current approach to network programming and security/technology:

- RESTful web service written in PHP on the server.
- Use of .htaccess to enable nice PUT / GET address commands.
- MySQL database with user name, password, **and** data fields, e.g. in game purchased items, in game currency.
- Salted & hashed passwords.

Is this approach is acceptable, i.e. is it secure? Or perhaps it's overkill; is there anything missing in general with respect to security?

Should I store id, username, and salted/hashed passwords in a **users** database, and then store user data, e.g. in app purchased items, in game currency, in a separate **data** database, which is indexed by the id in the user database?

I will be implementing HTTPS, so communication between client/server is secure, and authorization tokens, so that I know my server is communicating with whom it should be. ([This](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2016/01/using-google-sign-in-with-your-server.html) seems a good tutorial.)

Using authorization tokens means I probably don't need to store/deal with username and passwords directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Security:**

You have some elements of best practices, but there are some things missing.

- Use HTTPS so that the traffic between the Android app and your PHP web server is encrypted. Otherwise anyone can "wiretap" and see what's in the packets going back and forth. Read https://blog.hartleybrody.com/https-certificates/ and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-apache-in-ubuntu-16-04
- You only want people running your Android app to submit REST API requests. But anyone using a browser or running curl code can reach your REST server. You need to use authentication, so access to your REST API is restricted to legitimate clients. For example, see https://stormpath.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-mobile-api-security
- Please also read the book [Essential PHP Security](http://phpsecurity.org/). Any web developer should learn proper security practices, in the same way that an electrician needs to learn how to do safe wiring to prevent accidental fires.

**Database design:**

You seem to be using the word "database" where I would expect you to say "table." Yes, you can and should have multiple tables on your MySQL server. The application I support has over 120 tables, and there are certainly many applications with many more tables. It depends on the complexity of the data you need to store.

Here's a good book to start with: [Database Design for Mere Mortals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201752840)

If you want to get more into the theory behind the practice, I enjoyed [SQL and Relational Theory: How to Write Accurate SQL Code 3rd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491941170).

And I have to plug my own book: [SQL Antipatterns Volume 1: Avoiding the Pitfalls of Database Programming](https://pragprog.com/titles/bksap1/sql-antipatterns-volume-1/).